# Generated Julia function seems to always recompile

Tags: julia, metaprogramming, anonymous-function

I wrote a function in Julia that generates a bunch of anonymous functions, something like this:

```
function gen_funcs()
    funcs = []
    for i = 1:1000
        txt = "(a, b) -> some code"
        push!(funcs, eval(Meta.parse(txt)))
    end

    return funcs
end
```

Then I get this array of functions and use them somehow:

```
funcs = gen_funcs()
samples = [ rand(2) for i = 1:1000 ]
@time [ f(x...) for f in funcs for x in samples ]
```

I noticed that most of the execution time is compilation time.  And, more interestingly, if I run the `@time ...` line again, I get the same high compilation time.

If on the other hand I generate the `funcs` array myself in the source code doing something like:

```
funcs = [ (a, b) -> a^i * b^j for i = 1:100 for j = 1:100 ]
```

(for instance), then the execution is much faster.

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you compile 1000 functions, in the second case 1 function.

Comment: Why does it keep recompiling though if I run the command again?

Comment: The eval generates new functions. Those have to be compiled.